# TO_DATE Conversion Issue in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
 SELECT TO_DATE (   TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM schedule.start_date))
                || '-'
                || TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (DAY FROM schedule.start_date))
                || '-'
                || TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM schedule.start_date))
                || ' '
                || TO_CHAR (schedule.start_time_hour)
                || ':'
                || TO_CHAR (schedule.start_time_minutes)
                || schedule.start_time_am_pm,
                'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI pm'
                )
   FROM table1 schedule;
```

In `table1` the start_date field value contains the date as `14-Apr-12 12:00:00 AM`,   `start_time_hour` has the value of the `hour`, `start_time_minutes` has the value of `minutes` , `start_time_am_pm` has the value of `AM or PM`. I want to merge this columns into a string from that. I am going convert into date format like `to_date('14-04-12 05:08 PM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI PM')`. But it throws the error `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. What is the issue on this.. Can any help me how to convert into date format with my above requirment.

Comment: Please answer honestly: are you able to read your own question?

Comment: You already have a date! Why are you trying to convert to a date? Why are you storing hours and minutes and AM/PM when you already have this information?

Comment: schedule.start_date contains hour an minutes or is truncated at 00:00 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select to_char(schedule.start_date,  'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') 
from table1 schedule;
```

IF schedule.start_date is truncated at 00:00 and you have time info in the columns start_time_hour and start_time_minutes(*bad design - you don't need these columns, DATE type has time itself.*) you can do this:

```
Select 
  to_char(schedule.start_date + start_time_hour/24 + start_time_minutes/1440
          ,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') 
from table1 schedule;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your problem [not to mention the other comments] is that you are putting MONTH (character string) into MM (number).
i.e. EXTRACT (MONTH FROM schedule.start_date), so "MONTH" is the first date item from column, but format mask "DD" is the first item.